# Is there any good emacs keybinding extension for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, emacs, google-chrome-extension, shortcut, key-bindings

I know there are some excellent extensions on Firefox for operating the browser like vi or emacs.

So I found some extensions(vimmum, emacssome, emacs-mode, etc...) declare it have the same functions.
    But, all of them work so bad in chrome, most of shortcut can't work at start tab; Some of shortcut conflict with Chrome default setting.So...

1. Is there some way i can forbiden default shortcut of chrome, and make those extensions work at start(the first) tab.
2. Is there any good keybinding(It would be better like emacs style) extension perform well in chrome?

thanks a lot,

Comment: I think you should ask this in SuperUser